# Fatal error on Android 7.1.2(API 25) after execution of Garbage Collection

Tags: android, garbage-collection, fatal-error

If use app 3 to 4 min, I always end up with Fatal error which comes after the execution of Garbage collection.

I have almost optimised memory usage, however, my app crashes with Fatal error.

Here is the log,

```
08-30 04:59:48.603 W/InputEventReceiver(29468): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
08-30 04:59:48.943 I/SearchCardActivity(29468): onDestroy
08-30 04:59:48.944 I/art     (29468): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
08-30 04:59:49.054 I/art     (29468): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 37724(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 17(2020KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 1.180ms total 109.379ms
--------- beginning of crash
08-30 04:59:49.083 F/libc    (29468): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x44789914 in tid 29475 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post code please

Comment: Hi @JakeB, it's happening across all classes not stable in single class, if GC happens in ClassOne it'll come, if GC at ClassTwo it'll come. That's why I haven't pasted code, I suspect something going wrong after execution of GC.